# Write chars into file C++

Tags: c++

I have a function that writes random numbers into a file while reading another file.

```
void writeFile() {
    FILE* file = fopen(source, "r");
    FILE* file2 = fopen(target, "w");
    srand (time(NULL));

    while (!feof(file)) {
        fgetc(file);
        fputc(0 + ( rand() % ( 50 - 0 + 1 ) ), file2);
    }


    fclose(file);
    fclose(file2);
}
```

The two files should have the same size. What happens is that the second file has more 1byte at the end compared with the first file. How can I avoid this?

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: checking for EOF doesn't magically happen between the two lines of your while block.

Comment: If feof worked by predicting whether the next call to fgetc would return EOF then your code would be good. Unfortunately for you and the million other programmers who write code like this, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: ... and for us who have to keep letting people know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on `feof` to tell you that you've read all characters.  Instead, check the return value from `fgetc`:

```
while (fgetc(file) != EOF) {
    fputc(0 + ( rand() % ( 50 - 0 + 1 ) ), file2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as the EOF comments, you should also open both files in binary mode

```
FILE* file = fopen(source, "rb");
FILE* file2 = fopen(target, "wb");
```

In non-binary mode line endings may be translated (depending on platform). This potentially changes the number of characters read or written to a file.

Comment: Good spotting! =)  Perhaps add a quick one-liner to explain why this matters.

Answer (score 1):

The very final `fgetc(file)` reads EOF, then your code writes a byte for it into the new file and only *then* it tests for `feof` in the `while`.

Don't use `feof`, use this instead:

```
if (fgetc(file) == EOF) break;
```